# Can __$seqval be used to combine row changes in CDC

Tags: sql-server, cdc

Several versions from SQL Server 2012 to 2016 are being used :)

I am using several Change Tables(CTs), following is a sample data from one of the tables named 'Apartment'. The highlighted section shows data before and after update, for a row

[image]

As per the [SQL Server CDC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/cdc-fn-cdc-get-net-changes-capture-instance-transact-sql) :

1 = delete

2 = insert

4 = update

**My requirement is to club together these 'before and after update' records i.e, I should be able to identify the pair.
Now suppose each CT with n number of records is iterated over, without any ordering guarantees, the only way I think the pair can be identified is using the __$seqval column(note that in the data, the pair has the same value for __$seqval)** but I couldn't find any documentation endorsement for the same.

Comment: Is there any reason to use these table directly and not use the `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_<capture_instance>()` function for the table rather than going after the raw data? Perhaps I'm just not understanding the requirement(s), but at first glance, going after the raw data seems error prone.

Comment: I have tried that as well and can use it, right now, my doubt is if the before and update records can be combined.

Comment: Now that you say it that way, it sounds weird. What are you trying to do that you'd want to combine those records? That is, what business goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: E.g: An Apartment's area and renovation status is changed, now, there should be a file which has both the old and the new rows, one marked as 'before update' and the other as 'updated'

Comment: The `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_<capture_instance>` function takes a value for the filter option of 'all update old' that should do what you're looking for. Look at `__$operation` in the result set to determine which is which; 3 will be the old value and 4 the new one (within a given LSN that is).